# What kind of element is going to be returned from the function?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have created the following function:

```
const linkRenderer = (link: string) => 
    <a href={link} target={'_blank'} rel={'noopener'}/>;
```

I want to pass to the a function with this signature

```
function renderComponent(
  PageComponent: React.ComponentType<{ page: Page, anchorRenderer(link: string): React.Component}>
) {

....

   const page = new Page();
   const linkRenderer = (link: string) => <a href={link} target={'_blank'} rel={'noopener'}/>;
   return <PageComponent page={page}  anchorRenderer={linkRenderer} />
}
```

Typescript rejects the `React.Component` type of `anchorRenderer`. Here is the error message:

> Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'Component<{}, {}, any>'.
>       Property 'setState' is missing in type 'Element'.

So I want to switch the

```
React.ComponentType<{ page: Page, anchorRenderer(link: string): React.Component}>
```

to

```
React.ComponentType<{ page: Page, anchorRenderer(link: string): React.Element}>
```

[image]

However as you can see in the above screenshot, there are many `Element` type. Which one should I pick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `JSX.Element`, which is the type of any JSX element expression such as `<a href={link} target={'_blank'} rel={'noopener'}/>`.

However, using a custom function type for a function that returns a `JSX.Element` is somewhat unconventional.  It would be more conventional to let the link renderer be a real stateless function component that takes the link as a prop.  That is, `anchorRenderer` would be of type `React.ComponentType<{link: string}>`, and you would set:

```
const linkRenderer = (props: {link: string}) =>
    <a href={props.link} target={'_blank'} rel={'noopener'}/>;
```